# Should I have looked for invisible content while reviewing?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, declined-flags

Yesterday I reviewed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59556204) in the First Posts Queue. At the moment of reviewing all I saw from the answer was this:

> Fully mobile responsive designs that adjust to fit all platforms

As this isn't even a complete sentence I flagged as *Not an answer*. When I later returned to my raised flags page I found to my surprise that the flag was declined. I opened the post again and found that the incomplete sentence above was in fact an example text within HTML tags which were invisible due to a lack of code formatting.

At [the timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59556204/timeline) I could see that the edit which fixed the formatting happened 8 minutes after my flag. As this was most likely the revision the mod saw when handling the flag declining it was no doubt correct. But was my action correct as well (and the declined flag just bad luck) or should I have checked the answer for invisible HTML tags before flagging?

Comment: Personally I think this is more a "flaw" in the flagging system, and that when you flag a post you do so based on how it looks at the time you view it; not when the reviewer does. The flag should still be reviewed, even if an edit is performed later, but I think the way the prompt tells you it was "declined" is a little wrong when it likely wouldn't have been if the post had not been improved (either by the OP or another user). As users, I don't feel we should be obliged/expected to constantly check our pending flags, and remove them appropriately to avoid the flag being declined.

Comment: It may not have been a mod that declined your flag. I *think* it works like this for NAN flags: when one is raised, that post goes into the LQP review queue; if enough others (not sure what the required number is) similarly flag it, then it is deleted. But if others (again, not sure how many are required) click "Looks OK" in that LQP queue, then your flag will be removed from the post, and *automatically* show as "declined". ... Or maybe I'm getting confused with "disputed" flags?

Comment: … but, either way, I wouldn't worry too much about one or two *occasional* declined flags. I think you'll need 5 or so in a few days for your 'flagging score' to be seriously affected.

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb and say, yes, you should have looked for "invisible content". One problem we get a lot of in first posts is not understanding markdown and formatting of code. I routinely run across posts with sentences like "I put my text in a , and it doesn't work." Turns out, after the a is `<p>` without the tick marks. It needs some editing help. That's what you're signing up to do in the First Posts Queue, as far as I know.

Comment: @Larnu I'd see more a flaw in the posting process. I'd like to see that the poster is warned that they might have forgotten code formatting when they post HTML that will not be rendered.

Comment: @AdrianMole I also think that the flag would be disputed if the outcome of LPQ review were _Looks OK_. As for having one declined - I have a good enough percentage of helpful flags to not care about one declined ;-)

Comment: @HereticMonkey If you could back this up with a more or less official statement (Help page, community consesus, ...) I'd be happy to accept it as an answer.

Comment: It was a moderator who declined your flag. It was reviewed *after* the edit was made, so presumably, the moderator who reviewed the flag thought it *did* look like an answer. I'm going to disagree, especially with that "strikethrough humor" having been added in. The whole thing reads like nonsense. It is gone now. As for what Heretic Monkey says regarding the process of reviewing, yes, you should absolutely look for "invisible content" as part of reviewing a post. You're looking to see if the post can be improved in any way. Fixing the formatting is a substantial improvement and quite needed.